# Run project when press button in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

I have two project one is windows form Assembly name "project_1" and the second project is consol project name "project_2" I used multiple startup project to run both and make "project_2" initialized, my question is there is any way to makes the "project_2" run when press button from project one???

Comment: If they are in the same solution, you can simply reference Project 2 from Project 1 and then initialize an instance of the Program class to access the main method. 

But, if they are not referenced, then build the console project and call the executable file using the Process class. If there are parameters involved you can use ProcessStartInfo as well to specify the parameters.

Comment: I explained that I used method to reference Project 2 from Project 1 and it runs when I run project 1 but I asked about a way to making it run with button click I mean it will run in every time I click button

Comment: As I have explained above, you can initialize and instance of the Program class of Project 2 from button click of the specific button in Project 1. Then call the main method as it is a console application.

Comment: Can you explain with example please

Comment: You'll have to use the Process class.  This is not very likely to be useful, getting processes to talk to each other across the process boundary wall is awkward.  Getting a console window in a winforms app is very easy to do, use Project > Properties> Application tab > Output type = "Console Application".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided code for both the forms application and console application.

### Windows Forms application

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AllocConsole();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(new string[] {});
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool AllocConsole();
}
```

Had to add the DllImport to access the unmanaged code.

### Console appplicaion

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var writer =
            new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Farttoos\Desktop\Nasser_Last\Crypto(AES)_Stego(text)_Final\Crypto_Stego\Dictionary.txt"))
        {
            Console.SetOut(writer);
            Console.Write("Hello World!");
            Act();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when put  AllocConsole(); it underlined with red ??

Comment: Have you imported all the required namespaces? What does the error message say?

Comment: I checked it, yes sorry I forget to add " private static extern bool AllocConsole()" but the redline is now under         [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

Comment: I have updated the answer with the required namespaces. Can you please add them and see if you can run the application?

Comment: I made like this one and it's worked, but in my project, I wonder how to using it, my main is like this

Comment: public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Farttoos\Desktop\Nasser\_Last\Crypto(AES)_Stego(text)_Final\Crypto_Stego\Dictionary.txt"))
            {
                Console.SetOut(writer);
               Console.Write("Hello World!");

                Act();
            }
        }

Comment: I have modified the answer to include your code. Please check if it is working for you.